# How to set multiType layout to RecyclerView?

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

In my application I want use `RecyclerView` to show some list.
But I want set **Multitype** `layouts`, and not set just one layout!
For this I write below codes and I can set **multitype** `layouts` and show me 2 layouts, but when run my code show me `layouts` such as below :

**My codes result image (with bug) :** 
[image]

**My Codes :**

```
mLayoutManager = new GridLayoutManager(mContext, SPAN_SIZE) {
    @Override
    public boolean canScrollVertically() {
        return true;
    }
};
mLayoutManager.setSpanSizeLookup(new GridLayoutManager.SpanSizeLookup() {
    @Override
    public int getSpanSize(int position) {
        return position == 7 ? 2 : 1;
    }
});
postsRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
```

this code is for set multitype views.

But I want show `recyclerView` items **such as below image :** 
[image]

How can I fix this bug? please help me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be checking for 9th element which means 8th index. So please change the code to

```
    @Override
    public int getSpanSize(int position) {
        return position == 8 ? 2 : 1;
    }
```